# geth balance is always 0, block chain seems synced

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

So I just started to mine ether, using claymore with ethermine pool. I created the ether wallet with geth.

I ran `geth --fast --cache=1024`, I believe this is to sync the blockchain. So ran that all night.

In another terminal, ran `geth attach`, then ran `eth.syncing` and it shows the following results:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4823469,
  highestBlock: 4824783,
  knownStates: 22966377,
  pulledStates: 22961243,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

So it seems to me to be synced.

now If I run the following commands, it always a balance of 0 ....

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
0
> eth.blockNumber
0
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
0
```

But my wallet has 0.06741 ETH according to etherchain.org ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not synced.

When the chain is fully synced, `eth.syncing` will be `false`. If you look, the `highestBlock` (where the network is at) is higher than `currentBlock` (where geth is at).

But why aren't you seeing anything? geth does not provide things such as balances when fast syncing (the default). If this is unacceptable (although it looks like you're most of the way there) You could potentially try parity's warp sync, which is insanely fast.

Comment: Do I need the chain to be fully synced before I can send ether? How do I go about syncing the blockchain without --fast? Can I import my geth wallet inside parity?

Comment: You can send ether without a fully synced client, yes. --syncmode "full" will do an even slower full sync, or "light" will do an experimental light client sync. And yes, parity will happily import geth keys.